# How to integrate Google Cloud Text-to-Speech with Meteor

Tags: meteor, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API in Meteor app, but get an error on the Meteor console and crash when trying to use the import function described in the instructions:

```
("Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)")
```

Here's what I've done (in app directory) before starting meteor:

1. meteor npm install google-tts-api
2. export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/data/authenticationinfo.json"

The problems are related to the inclusion of this line at the top of my js file:

```
import textToSpeech from '@google-cloud/text-to-speech';
```

This line cause the following Meteor startup error on the console:
    "Unable to resolve some modules: "http2" in /app/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js (web.browser)

```
If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

  meteor npm install --save meteor-node-stubs
```

Actually, I ran the above command, but it has no effect. When I run start the app, it crashes quickly with the error :

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.getPrototypeOf ()
    at module.exports (modules.js?hash=59a3378abff937a73bf3a9865d654fce71b9583a:91277)
    at index.js (modules.js?hash=59a3378abff937a73bf3a9865d654fce71b9583a:86991)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=b819d45cbf32aff410d740fac0364cb4088cd3f2:346)
    at Module.require (modules-runtime.js?hash=b819d45cbf32aff410d740fac0364cb4088cd3f2:248)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=b819d45cbf32aff410d740fac0364cb4088cd3f2:268)
    at jwtclient.js (modules.js?hash=59a3378abff937a73bf3a9865d654fce71b9583a:79821)
    at fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js?hash=b819d45cbf32aff410d740fac0364cb4088cd3f2:346)
    at Module.require (modules-runtime.js?hash=b819d45cbf32aff410d740fac0364cb4088cd3f2:248)
    at require (modules-runtime.js?hash=b819d45cbf32aff410d740fac0364cb4088cd3f2:268)

I have tested it on a barebones node app, and my Google authentication json file works fine, so that's definitely not the problem.

I realize there are are some Meteor packages for Google TTS, but they're really old and use Google Translate (which won't work for long) instead of the new cloud services.

Comment: If it's unable to resolve `http2` - have you also tried to manually add `http2` ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Adding that manually did eliminate the message about http2 on the meteor console, but this doesn't affect the "Uncaught TypeError" that is crashing the app the moment the "import" is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out the import has to happen on the server side, NOT the client side.